# How to change the columns titles In Grafana using ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I use Grafana to display ElasticSearch results in a table. The table's column names are the values of the term that is the results are grouped by.

In my case: I use the Average aggregation on the term "upgrade_time" and I group the results by the term "db_name".

How can I set the column name to show "Average Upgrade Time for db1", "Average Upgrade Time for db2", etc...?

Answer (score 0):

With ElasticSearch 6.4 and Grafana 6.2.5, the versions I am using you can use 
["Series naming & alias patterns"](https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/elasticsearch/#series-naming-alias-patterns)

e.g.,

Lets say you display the **average** value of the field **"upgrade time"** aggregated by the **term "db_name"**. By default, when no alias pattern is used, you will get columns titled: "db1", "db2", etc...

You can then use the pattern

```
RESULT_FOR_{{db_name}}
```

to change the titles to: **"RESULT_FOR_db1"**, "RESULT_FOR_db2", etc...

If you use the alias pattern

```
{{metric}}
```

the title will be "Average" for all columns, because the calculation used is the average function

If you use {{metric}}_{{db_name}}, the titles will be: **"Average_db1"**, "Average_db2", etc...

If you use

```
{{metric}}_{{field}}_{{db_name}}
```

the titles will be: **"Average_upgrade_time_db1"**, "Average_upgrade_time_db2", etc..., because the aggregated field is "upgrade_time".

Comment: I still haven't figured out if I can manipulate the strings in the alias pattern with regex or something similar to show a nicer title like "Upgrade Time" instead of the term name "upgrade_time".